# opencart php program stopped after dispatch()

Tags: php, opencart

My opencart front-end works well, while back-end /admin returns me blank page.
I debugged my /admin/index.php and find after 
$controller->dispatch($action, new Action('error/not_found'));
the program stopped. So I won't be able to see even the echo.
Here is the code:
**Back-end admin/index.php**

```
// Router
if (isset($request->get['route'])) {
    $action = new Action($request->get['route']);
} else {
    $action = new Action('common/home');
}

// Dispatch

var_dump($action);


$controller->dispatch($action, new Action('error/not_found'));

echo "second+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++";
var_dump($response);
// Output

$response->output();
```

**By the way the frond end works well, as it returned me echo and $response value after dispatch:**

```
if (isset($request->get['route'])) {

    $action = new Action($request->get['route']);

} else {

    $action = new Action($config->get('config_default_controller'));

}

// Dispatch
var_dump($action);
$controller->dispatch($action, new Action($config->get('config_default_controller_error')));

echo "second++++++++++++++++++++++++++";
var_dump($response);
```

I have checked the $action and $controller they are all with good values and paths.
Do anyone know what happened here with dispatch ? or give me any information about dispatch and why the program stop. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Did you found solution for this problem?

Answer (score 1):

after few hours i found solution.

In my case **it was wrong config**. I had same issue and after checking what is wrong i figure out that my **paths in config.php** file in **admin** folder was with wrong values.

Opencart **have two cfg** files.

Next thing what i changed was **config_url** in database. Hope it will help you.